# aiml <reply/> and <image/> tags doesn't work in android

Tags: android, tags, chatbot, aiml, reply

I'm working with android to create my own chatbot. but some tags don't work and I get something like that.
[image]

I really need help with this.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

These are rich media AIML 2.1 tags. Make sure whatever interpreter you are using supports AIML 2.1

Comment: Thank you for replying can you refer me to an interpreter for AIML 2.1.

Comment: Program AB can certainly handle AIML 2.0 https://code.google.com/archive/p/program-ab/ but I use https://www.pandorabots.com to handle AIML 2.1

Comment: how can I integrate the pandorabots API into my android app???

Comment: Probably worth contacting the good people of support@pandorabots.com

Comment: I purchased pandorabots Api to deal with AIML 2.1 but i have the same problem in android. I can't have the rich media such as images , reply and split.

Comment: Your application needs to convert AIML into appropriate code to render the rich media similar to what the chat widget does, or build an intermediate application that converts AIML rich media to protocols that messaging platforms like Messenger and Telegram require in their API.